# How to Remove white strip on top of wpf window after setting window style to none

Tags: c#, css, wpf

Hi I have created WPF window with custom title bar successfully.But the problem is White strip on the top of  the titlebar.I can remove the white strip if i set the ResizeMode = "NoResize".But I want my window to Resizable I just only want to remove the whitestrip at the top of window.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen in Windows 10.

It is the default re-size border. You can remove that and still make the window resizable by setting ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" AllowsTransparency="True"

[How to remove white strip on top of WPF window with WindowStyle=None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631165/how-to-remove-white-strip-on-top-of-wpf-window-with-windowstyle-none)